Does quantum entanglement arise from perpendicular time vectors?
From what I understand, "quantum entanglement" is a phenomenon where certain information  travels instantly between entangled particles, regardless of distance in space.
When thinking of spacetime being a coordinate system, it seems that time is sort of like an extra 4th axis in this system, so all particles experiencing time is due to having a constant vector of time that is pointing towards the positive direction of the time axis. But if we make the vector of time in the model be perpendicular, we get that the start and endpoint of this vector would not have a change in the value of time, so, in other words, instant travel. So could entangled particles be due to their vectors of time pointing towards one-another before one of them gets observed?
Also, since in a coordinate system each axis is perpendicular to all other axis, it seems to me that space itself (the 3 axis of space together) is fundementally entangled with itself, and so my question can also be reworded as: Does quantum entanglement arise from the time vector of a particle overlapping with space vectors?

quantum entanglement famously cannot be used to send information faster than light.

When you see spacetime as a 4 dimensional object (search "minkowski space"), you can rotate the perpendicular time and x axes for an observer that is moving.  In order for the time axis to switch with a length axis you need to travel at as speed faster than that of light. Actually, at an infinite speed relative to the initial observer. Relativity forbids this, but some people might disagree. Search for "Tachions".

First, what you are proposing as a “perpendicular” time axis is a new dimension, making 5 rather than the traditional 4. Considering how well general relativity does with four (and not five), that’s a big problem for your idea.
Second, Quantum entanglement arises from the mathematics and principles of quantum mechanics.  QM properly explains the many many experiments which have been performed over the last 50 years.  As of now, there are no unexplained effects open to an explanation such as yours.
